# How to create a directive inside a service in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I need to create a directive inside angular service and then on an event insert element with that directive into dom and compile it, the inserting and compiling seems to be working fine, but it seems that directives created dynamically from inside angular (controller, service or wherever) don't register or something.

Here's a simplified version of my current code

```
var dirs = angular.module('dirs', []);

dirs.factory('directiveCreator', function($rootScope) {

    var creator = {};

    creator.addDirective = function(config) {

        dirs.directive(config.name, function() {
            return {
               restrict: config.restrict,
               template: config.template,
               replace: config.replace,
           }
       });

       //insert element with the directive above into DOM on this event and compile
       $rootScope.$broadcast('directive.added');

    }

    return creator;
}
```

The directive is added to invokeQueue properly on the module, but it doesn't work at all, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to capture the `$compileProvider` and then use the `directive` method instead of using the `moduleObj.directive` method

```
var dirs = angular.module('dirs', []);
dirs.config(function($compileProvider){
   dirs.compileProvider = $compileProvider;
});
```

then when you need to dynamically include the new directive

```
creator.addDirective = function(config) {
    dirs.compileProvider.directive(config.name, function() {
        return {
           restrict: config.restrict,
           template: config.template,
           replace: config.replace,
       }
   });
   //insert element with the directive above into DOM on this event and compile
   $rootScope.$broadcast('directive.added');
}
```

This is lazy loading, [***Here***](http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/) is an article that I found helpful in doing such things